# android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: htc, force-close

After updating Android I got this error. During update android asked me to move some of app to sd card as there were not enough space for update. I moved some and after update and restart I can't enter contacts. When I press green button for calls (enter contacts) it shows error: android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly

I'm using HTC Cha Cha.

I try t reboot phone, to put battery out and back. Finally I try restore phone to factory settings by removing all apps and data.

And I still have this error - android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly

Can you please tell me how to fix it without taking phone to service.

Phone is brought from US to EU, so I would need to pay service if I can't fix it myself.

Comment: Updated my ChaCha yesterday to 2.3.5 and I have the same problem :( Via a workaround I can still call: Call History. Updates should make things better, not worse!

Comment: I would try a factory reset.

Comment: Factory reset didn't help... Any more ideas? Is it possible to revert to the previous htc version?

Answer (score 4):

I updated my HTC ChaCha over the air (OTA) to 2.3.5 two days ago.

Identical issue. Keep getting same error whenever I press the green call button or a number to start dialing or attempt to start the "Phone" app.

I don't have a "Contacts" app any more.

I believe the issue is in an app called "Dialer" because that's what displays when I tell my phone to report the issue to HTC.

Work around:

- use the favourites (people) widget that comes, by default, on the second screen. Press the right arrow and you'll go to your contacts list. From there you can call your contacts - or add new contacts and call them.

Note that the phone does receive calls okay.

This is an outrageous bug. The software update should NEVER have been pushed.

Additional issue in 2.3.5: the initial boot up "Enter PIN" screen isn't sized correctly for the ChaCha - there are some white line dots at the top of that screen - presumably the bottom of the text saying "Enter PIN" - but all you see is the text input field and the "OK"/"Cancel" buttons. Also it seems this phone requires a SIM PIN even when none is set. Further - if you type your PIN wrong 3 times it doesn't tell you that it is expecting the PUK.

I think HTC have got serious issues when it comes to software development. I wish CyanogenMod was available for the HTC ChaCha - because it was the ONLY way I could use my HTC Desire Z (default HTC software for that had show-stopping issues, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [these instructions from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=792691):

> WARNING!: This will wipe contacts. It seems acore fc's when there are
>   corrupted contacts. Usually by restoring contacts on an incompatible
>   ROM.... And will temporarily wipe market list. So backup your
>   contacts!
>
> Step by step:
>
> 1. Make sure Sync is off, leave it off for some time!
> 2. Go into settings
> 3. Select Applications
> 4. Select Manage Applications
> 5. (If you are on 2.2) Select the All tab
> 6. Scroll down until you find Contacts Storage (select it).
> 7. Wipe data+clear cache(If available)
> 8. Hit back
> 9. Scroll down until you find Google Services Framework (select it)
> 10. Wipe data+clear cache (if available)
> 11. Reboot and enjoy
> 12. (optional) Enable Sync again Enable sync again when your convinced that the error has gone.

Comment: Can you outline the information contained there?  If the link goes dead, this answer (as-is) will be useless.

Comment: i have those problems and do that things , nothing changed